# Debian Installer Kernel parameter syntax

Tags: linux, kernel, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to pass kernel arguments to pxelinux.cfg/default using the APPEND directive but I can't seem to get the correct syntax. What is the proper way to send this debian installer command?

d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually

I have tried

APPEND netcfg/dhcp_options=Configure network manually

but that does not seem to work.

I am trying to bypass the failed to setup DHCP prompt during a PXE installation.

Comment: Does no one know anything about pxelinux? I swear there is no documentation on how correctly pass these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ubuntu [manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/arm64/apbs02.html#preseed-bootparms):

```
Note
It may not always be possible to specify values with spaces for boot parameters, even if you delimit them with quotes.
```

I bet that's the cause why it's not working. You can put that command on a `preseed.cfg` file, like this:

```
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually
```

Comment: I actually ended up passing quotations around the value I passed for netcfg/dhcp_options. So what ended up working was:
netcfg/dhcp_options="Do not configure the network at this time" Passed in the pxelinux.cfg/default file.